# VBA- How do I prevent my button deleting itself after running the code?

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I click on the CommandButton which runs the code, it gets deleted. But I want to use it again. All those IF-Statements are referring to ToggleButtons. If they are clicked, the CommandButton called CREATE inserts the relevant Files.

```
Public Sub CREATE_CLICK()  `this is the command button`
 
    
    If MAV.Value = True Then
    
          Selection.InsertBreak
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MAV Fertig.docx"
    
    End If
    
    If MCS.Value = True Then
       
    
         Selection.InsertBreak
            Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MCS Fertig.docx"
    
    End If
    
    If MDC.Value = True Then
     
       Selection.InsertBreak
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MDC Fertig.docx"
    
    End If
    
    If MGB.Value = True Then
       
       Selection.InsertBreak
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MGB.docx"
    
    End If
    
    If MUP.Value = True Then
       
       Selection.InsertBreak
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MUP Fertig.docx"
    
    End If
    
    If MVT.Value = True Then
       
       Selection.InsertBreak
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MVT.docx"
    
    End If
    
    If MVK.Value = True Then
       
       Selection.InsertBreak
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MVK.docx"
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In a  normal world such a thing cannot happen. If you do not show your code, nobody can help you. Maybe your button is created on the fly (on a form). What button type are you talking about?

Comment: i added the code

Comment: There's no line in your code that deletes a commandbutton.  Is that the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

After using the Macro Recorder, your code is specific to the Selection object, which leads to unexpected results when you try to make the macro more generalized. Since your button is on the page, when you click on it, it becomes the selection and your code replaces it.

Instead, use ranges to define the place where the document should be inserted. A convenient method is to use a bookmark at the preferred location. This code assumes that a bookmark called **InsertPoint** has been added to the document below the ActiveX button.

```
Private Sub CREATE_Click()
    Dim oRange As Range
    
    If MAV.Value = True Then
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InsertPoint").Range
            .InsertBreak
            .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MAV Fertig.docx"
        End With
    End If
    If MCS.Value = True Then
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InsertPoint").Range
            .InsertBreak
            .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MCS Fertig.docx"
        End With
    End If
    If MDC.Value = True Then
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InsertPoint").Range
            .InsertBreak
            .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MDC Fertig.docx"
        End With
    End If
    If MGB.Value = True Then
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InsertPoint").Range
            .InsertBreak
            .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MGB Fertig.docx"
        End With
    End If
    If MUP.Value = True Then
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InsertPoint").Range
            .InsertBreak
            .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MUP Fertig.docx"
        End With
    End If
    If MVT.Value = True Then
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InsertPoint").Range
            .InsertBreak
            .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MVT Fertig.docx"
        End With
    End If
    If MVK.Value = True Then
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InsertPoint").Range
            .InsertBreak
            .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\AZI\Documents\Schnellbaustein MVK Fertig.docx"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```